# MATE on 18.04 panel disappeared -- error on reset

Tags: 18.04, menu, mate

I have re-installed mate desktop environment, but this issue persists. No panels, no menu.Hotkeys are responsive and GUI applications load without issue.

dconf editor browses the panel without complaint.

There is this:

```
 mate-panel --reset
 mate-panel: symbol lookup error: mate-panel: undefined symbol: matemenu_tree_unref
```

And from the journal this:

```
WARNING: Unable to find provider 'mate-panel' of required component 'panel'
```

For N0rbert

```
 apt-cache policy mate-panel python-mate-menu libmate-menu2
 mate-panel:
   Installed: 1.20.1-3ubuntu1
   Candidate: 1.20.1-3ubuntu1
   Version table:
  *** 1.20.1-3ubuntu1 500
         500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 python-mate-menu:
   Installed: 1.20.0-2
   Candidate: 1.20.0-2
   Version table:
  *** 1.20.0-2 500
         500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 libmate-menu2:
   Installed: 1.20.0-2
   Candidate: 1.20.0-2
   Version table:
  *** 1.20.0-2 500
         500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

After re-installing the packages referenced:

```
 mate-panel --replace
 mate-panel: symbol lookup error: mate-panel: undefined symbol matemenu_tree_unref
 cat .xsession-errors
```

I had archived and then emptied .xsession-errors before issuing the replace. After --replace the file is empty.

N0rbert asks is it a python issue? Note that we have mate-menu on board and will not uninstall

```
 pip uninstall mate-menu
 Not uninstalling mate-menu at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside 
environment /usr


 pip list 
 asn1crypto (0.24.0)
 autokey (0.90.4)
 backports.functools-lru-cache (1.5)
 cajarename (17.3.28)
 configobj (5.0.6)
 cryptography (2.1.4)
 cycler (0.10.0)
 duplicity (0.7.17)
 enum34 (1.1.6)
 fasteners (0.12.0)
 folder-color-common (0.0.86)
 funcsigs (1.0.2)
 idna (2.6)
 ipaddress (1.0.17)
 keyring (10.6.0)
 keyrings.alt (3.0)
 kiwisolver (1.0.1)
 lockfile (0.12.2)
 mate-menu (18.4.3)
 mock (2.0.0)
 monotonic (1.0)
 pbr (3.1.1)
 pip (9.0.1)
 pycairo (1.16.2)
 pycrypto (2.6.1)
 pygobject (3.26.1)
 pyinotify (0.9.6)
 pyparsing (2.2.0)
 python-dateutil (2.7.2)
 python-xlib (0.20)
 pytz (2018.4)
 pyxdg (0.25)
 SecretStorage (2.3.1)
 setproctitle (1.1.10)
 setuptools (39.0.1)
 simplejson (3.13.2)
 six (1.11.0)
 subprocess32 (3.2.7)
 wheel (0.30.0)
 X-Tile (2.5.1)
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy mate-panel python-mate-menu libmate-menu2` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert Output pasted into question. The 500 errors? That URL is accessible. I don't get 500 error. The three packages show as installed 'already the newest version. '

Comment: 500 is priority, it is [normal value](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/apt_preferences.5.html). I have exactly the same versions. You can try to reinstall these packages with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mate-panel python-mate-menu libmate-menu2` and then try to relaunch MATE Panel with `mate-panel --replace &` and post error output here (look `~/.xsession-errors`).

Comment: @N0rbert No change. The re-install went without error . I have added the output to the question.  I re-ran the policy command you suggested and saw that output is the same.

Comment: Very strange. I can't reproduce your issue on clean 18.04 LTS MATE. Do you have any MATE-related PPAs in your system?

Comment: @N0rbert No MATE-related PPAs in /etc/apt -- assuming that MATE -related will be found via a grep -i for mate. I'm thinking I may have knocked something while I was doing some building a few days ago. I have a test user and it has the same issue so it's not in a personal setting.  I keep my data and home on a second disk so I can easily re-install. I'll go ahead with that plan -- unless you have another idea. Be nice to figure it out.

Comment: May be python issue - please add output of `pip list` to the question. On clean system the output is empty (and does not contain MATE-related components).

Comment: I checked again - my system also lists *mate-menu (18.4.3)* in `pip list`. So I do not have more ideas. But you can check system integrity with [`debsums`](https://askubuntu.com/q/9463/66509).

Comment: @N0rbert. I apt re-installed mate-panel with no change. debsums ok too. So I've deleted that VM. Thanks for the help. This comment history is a good diagnostic procedure.